# Prevent URL change on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, submit

I'm working on a website.

- I have index.html page with div container and I load all the other pages into this div.
- I have *window.onhashchange* function that refreshes the page on url change and loads corresponding html file into that div
- I have javascript/ajax contact form.

**Problem:**
When I click "submit" I expect success or error message to change class and  appear under my form. However, "submit" button adds "?" to my URL and, consequently, my page refreshes and all the elements load with default classes.

**Question:** How can I prevent my "submit" button from adding "?" to my URL? Or am I doing it all wrong?

Codes are shown below:

submit function in my .js file:

```js
$(".form-horizontal").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var fname = $("#first-name").val();
    var lname = $("#last-name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var subject = $("#subject").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();
    var dataString = 'fname=' + fname + 'lname=' + lname + '&email=' + email + '&subject=' + subject + '&message=' + message;

    function isValidEmail(emailAddress) {
        var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
        return pattern.test(emailAddress);
    };

    if (isValidEmail(email) && (message.length > 1) && (fname.length > 1)) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sendmail.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function () {
                $('.contact-success').fadeIn(1000);
                $('.contact-error').fadeOut(500);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('.contact-error').fadeIn(1000);
        $('.contact-success').fadeOut(500);
    }

    return false;
});
```

php file:

```
<?php
// Email Submit
// Note: filter_var() requires PHP >= 5.2.0
if ( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['fname']) &&      isset($_POST['lname']) && isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['message']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {

// detect & prevent header injections
$test = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
if ( preg_match( $test, $val ) ) {
  exit;
}
}

//
mail( "email@domain.com", $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message'],     "From:" . $_POST['email'] );
 
}
?>
```

**Update:**
Thank you very much for suggestions in the comments!

[Errors that I get on submit. I also get them on some of my pages.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iMhA.png)

- I checked, it is wrapped in `$(document).ready(function()`.
- Form does have class `<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">`.

In case I won't be able to figure it out, I guess I'll just create separate "Thank you for submitting your message" page. Kind of workaround ))

*does element exist when code is run?* - need to think more about it! I'll check!

Comment: Open the browser console (F12) and check for errors, the `preventDefault` should already prevent any URL change when the form submits

Comment: Also, I believe submit function only fires on forms, so verify that your form contains the `.form-horizontal` class, with correct spelling and all.

Comment: does element exist when code is run? Is it wrapped in `document.ready`? Any errors in browser console before or while it submits?

Comment: Updated my question. Thanks!

Comment: `console.log($(".form-horizontal").length); $(".form-horizontal").submit(......`